# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, etc

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax-error, average

I have SQL query below where I am attempting to average a set of integers over the last 5 minutes. But I am getting the error that the subquery is returning more than one value, which is what I want it to do, I am just unaware of how to get the average for the top 300 values like I am wanting.

```
SELECT  AVG(value) AS AVERAGE,
        id_num
FROM    table_name 
AS C
WHERE   C.time=(SELECT TOP 300 time FROM table_name)
GROUP BY id_num
```

Comment: Your inner sub-select needs an `ORDER BY` clause, otherwise you have no guarantee *which* 300 times you will get.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using the = operator, use the IN operator

```
SELECT AVG(value) AS AVERAGE, id_num 
FROM table_name AS C WHERE C.time IN (SELECT TOP 300 time FROM table_name ORDER BY TIME) 
GROUP BY id_num
```

edit: added order by as suggested

Comment: This is almost the perfect answer. However, using TOP without an order by means we don't know which 300 rows will be returned by the subquery.

Comment: So add `ORDER BY time` to the subquery, assuming by `TOP` we mean "shortest".

Answer (score 2):

Hard to say without knowing what `time` in your table represents, but if you want the last 5 minutes, maybe something like this would work better:

```
Select ID_num, avg(value) as [average]
from table_name
group by ID_num
where time >= dateadd(minute, -5, getdate())
```

Edit: to get the last 5 minutes from the table, not just the last 5 minutes ever.  The variable `@lasttime` is unnecessary - you can just put the whole `max` in the `dateadd` - but I think it is easier to follow this way.

```
declare @lastTime datetime = (select max(time) from table_name)

Select ID_num, avg(value) as [average]
from table_name
group by ID_num
where time >= dateadd(minute, -5, @lastTime)
```

Comment: The thing is, I am not working with recent data. I would like it to give me the last five minutes that are logged in the table. The time represents when each data event happens and is updated every second, which is why I need the last 300 points.The time is in the format "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss:ms"

Comment: Makes sense.  You could replace the `getdate()` in my solution with `select max(time) from Table_name` (I will edit to show this example), but using what others have suggested (with the addition of `desc` to the `order by`) may make more sense.